Does increase of effective compression ratio increase thermal efficiency?
Does increase of effective compression ratio increase thermal efficiency of a turbo engine or does efficiency only depend on static compression ratio?
Is high effective compression ratio a reason why a turbo engine has higher thermal efficiency than a naturally aspirated engine?

You might want to change "effective" to "dynamic", as I've never heard the term "effective" used when talking about compression ratios. I believe dynamic is actually what you're talking about.

Your previous question suggested that turbo engines have lower compression ratio. As stated there, the efficiency comes from reducing energy waste in the exhaust.

Attempting to combine compression ratio, turbocharging and thermal efficiency into one question cannot be answered. CR, turbocharging and TE are three separate parameters that must to be understood relative to internal combustion engines.  For example, the following links can describe thermal efficiency; https://en.demotor.net/heat-engine/cycles/4-stroke-engine/thermal-performance, http://www.epi-eng.com/piston_engine_technology/thermal_efficiency.htm, and https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/engine-thermal-efficiency. Increasing compression or turbocharging does not increase TE. As you'll find out, TE is between 18%-35% in 4-stroke engines no matter how high CR is or using turbo/super charging. Turbo/super charging means forcing more air into a cylinder that requires more fuel in correct stoichiometric ratios for proper combustion for more power while TE remains the same. Heat generated from combustion is waste energy, heating up coolant, oil, engine block, overcoming friction in the drivetrain, etc. TE is energy used to do actual work while the rest is wasted energy.

Turbocharging increases thermal efficiency, since a turbo engine makes more power, but is of the same size so friction losses don't increase proportionally to the power production. A turbo engine generally has somewhat higher thermal efficiency than a non-turbo engine. The downsizing trend (small turbos instead of large naturally aspirated engine) isn't only because of the fact that making a small engine block is cheaper, it's also due to fuel consumption -- which is due to better thermal efficiency of turbo engines.

I respectfully disagree. As mentioned previously, forced air requires more fuel to stay as stoichiometric (14.7:1), therefore no increase in TE. More air and fuel simply means more power, not TE. TE gains are miniscule compared to power gains.

Indeed. More air, more fuel, more power, but not proportionally more friction losses so TE gains are true. Indeed, power gains are far greater than TE gains, but that doesn't make TE gains non-existent. So you can't increase from 36% thermal efficiency to 54% thermal efficiency. But you can increase from 36% thermal efficiency to maybe 38%.


Does increase of effective compression ratio increase thermal efficiency of a turbo engine or does efficiency only depend on static compression ratio?

The answer is yes.
A turbocharged engine produces more power. Effective compression ratio is basically measuring the amount of turbocharging done, which means if you have a larger effective compression ratio, your turbo engine produces more power.
Friction losses don't increase proportionally to the power production. Turbocharging doesn't make the engine larger.
So a turbocharged engine of the same power is smaller and uses less fuel. This is the downsizing trend. Not only is making a small engine block cheaper, but also a small turbo engine uses less fuel than an equivalent larger naturally aspirated engine that produces the same power.
So the thermal efficiency increases if you do more turbocharging.
Note that fuel consumption probably doesn't get better if displacement is fixed, since a car needs only so much power. If you take an existing engine, and boost its power production by turbocharging, you increase the power it produces, and you increase its thermal efficiency at its new optimal operating point, but the new optimal operating point is at such a high power that it isn't used in normal traffic situations.
So to make the thermal efficiency visible in fuel consumption figures, you need downsizing. Pick a smaller engine, add a turbo, now you have an engine that produces as much power as a larger naturally aspirated engine, but uses less fuel.

Is high effective compression ratio a reason why a turbo engine has higher thermal efficiency than a naturally aspirated engine?

No. If you think some mathematical formula where you can enter an effective compression ratio is going to give the thermal efficiency, it doesn't.
The reason is that a turbo engine produces more power. It doesn't have proportionally larger friction losses. That's the reason for turbo engines being more thermally efficient.
The mathematical formulas ignore so many real-life effects that they give way too good thermal efficiencies, something that can't be achieved in real life.
